# Not sure how to calculate entropy change in a quasi-static isobaric expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I'm working on a problem that states:

> Volume of $n$ moles of ideal monatomic gas increased from $V_0$ to $2V_0$ at constant $P_0$ in a quasi-static process. Calculate $\Delta W$, $\Delta Q$, $\Delta E$, and $\Delta S$.

In class, we derived $dS$ as such:

Consider the first law

$$
dE= dQ-PdV$$
since $dE=nC_vdT$, where $C_v$ is specific heat at constant volume,
$$
nC_vdT=dQ-PdV
$$
Since $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$
$$
dS= \frac{nC_v}{T}dT+\frac{P}{T}dV
$$
by the ideal gas law $\frac{P}{T}=\frac{Nk}{V}$,
$$
dS=nC_v\frac{dT}{T}+Nk\frac{dV}{V}
$$
integrating from initial state $i$ to final state $f$, this yields
$$
\Delta S =nC_v\log\frac{T_f}{T_i}+Nk\log\frac{V_f}{V_i} \tag{1}
$$

However, since the process here is isobaric, I can't just use eq. 1 above, correct? Do I instead use the fact that $dQ=nC_pdT$ at constant pressure, thus
$$
dS=\frac{nC_pdT}{T}
$$
integrating to yield
$$
\Delta S = nC_p\log\frac{T_f}{T_i}
$$
since $T=\frac{PV}{nR}$, $\frac{T_f}{T_i}=\frac{2P_0V_0}{nR}\frac{nR}{P_0V_0}=2$ therefore
$$
\Delta S = nC_p\log2
$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For an ideal gas,

$$C_{p}-C_{v}=nR$$

Hope this helps.